# Mysql delete duplicate base on email but keep the longest row-sum-length record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code for deleting duplicate based on email and keep larget id record:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id)
                            FROM mytable n
                        GROUP BY n.email) x)
```

Now I write this code for  base on email but keep the longest row-sum-length record:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
 WHERE (char_length(firstname) + char_length(lastname) + char_length(location) + char_length(address)) NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(char_length(n.firstname) + char_length(n.lastname) + char_length(n.location) + char_length(n.address))
                            FROM mytable n
                        GROUP BY n.email) x)
```

the weird thing is, it work for a small table, but for my large table, it just run a sec and show nothing effect. Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is quite dangerous.  It might work for ids, but not for lengths which could be in common across different rows.  Instead, use a `join`:

```
DELETE t
    FROM mytable t JOIN
         (SELECT email,
                 (char_length(firstname) + char_length(lastname) + 
                  char_length(location) + char_length(address)
                 )  as len
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY email
         ) tt
         ON t.email = tt.email
    WHERE (char_length(t.firstname) + char_length(t.lastname) + 
           char_length(t.location) + char_length(t.address)
          ) <> tt.len;
```

Comment: thanks for reply, how can I fix this error?  :1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "t" at position 7)